# Evaluate $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1-e^{-ax}}{x e^x} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I found two different approaches, both is giving the same answer.

1. Fubini: 
   $$
   \begin{align}
   \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1-e^{-ax}}{x e^x} \,dx &= \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} \int_0^a e^{-xy} \,dy\, dx \\
   &=  \int_0^a \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x(1+y)}\, dx \,dy \\
   &= \int_0^{a} \frac{1}{1+y}\, dy\\
   &=\log (a+1) , a>-1
   \end{align}
   $$
2. Differentiation of the parameter:
   Denote $\displaystyle K(a) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1-e^{-ax}}{x e^x}\, dx$, differentiate w.r.t. $a$. Also, note that $K(0)=0$.

$$
\begin{align}
K'(a) &= \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-ax}}{e^x} \,dx\\
&=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x(a+1)} \,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{a+1}\\
\end{align}
$$

Now we integrate back to get $\displaystyle K(a) = \int K'(a) da = \log(a+1), a>-1$

The requirements of the Fubini theorem are that $f(a,x)$ is a measurable function and $(0,a) \times (0,\infty)$ is a measurable set, right?

To differentiate w.r.t. a parameter, we need that $\displaystyle | e^{-x(a+1)}| \le g(x)$ which has to be an integrable function. Here we could have $g(x)=e^{-x}$ for instance.

So my question now is, whether one of the approaches is more correct than the other. I used 1. in an exam, and got a really low score (so I'm surprised).

Comment: You forgot that $f$ has to be absolutely integrable wrt. the product measure (which can e.g. be shown by Lebesgue dominated covergence). See also [this statement of Fubini](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Fubini's_Theorem).

Comment: meaning, that I need to find an integrable $g(x)$ satisfying $|f(x,y)| \le g(x)$?

Comment: Yes, that would be sufficient (since $[0,a]$ has finite measure).

Comment: then $g(x)=e^{-x}$ should do the job

Comment: @Lord_Farin Fubini requires that $(0,\infty) \times (0,a)$ be $\sigma$-finite. But as far as I can see its measure is infinity. Can I still use Fubini?

Comment: That set is $\sigma$-finite under Lebesgue measure -- be sure to (re)read the definition of [$\sigma$-finite](http://enwp.org/%CE%A3-finite_measure).

Comment: @Lord_Farin So should I also be finding an integrable $h(y) \ge |f(x,y)|$? And if not in this case, how about in general?

Comment: Because I must prove that $\int_M |f| d (\mu \times \nu) < \infty$

Comment: No. In general, it suffices to find an integrable $h(x,y) \ge |f(x,y)|$. In the above case, we chose $h(x,y) = g(x) \ge |f(x,y)|$. If you have more questions, please do not ask them in these comments. I suggest you read more sources on the subject, ask your professor (should you have one) and for specific further questions, just use the "Ask Question" button. :)

Comment: I think you can use the Fubini theorem because the condition for the theorem is either the function is absolutely integrable or non-negative. Your function falls into the second category.

Answer (score 1):

I have a third approach relying on interchanging summation and integration:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1-e^{-ax}}{x e^x} \ \mathrm dx
&=& \displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} \frac{-1}{x e^x} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-ax)^n}{n!} \ \mathrm dx \\
&=& \displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} \frac{a^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} x^n e^{-x} \ \mathrm dx \\
&=& \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{a^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} x^n e^{-x} \ \mathrm dx \\
&=& \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{a^{n+1} n!}{(n+1)!} \\
&=& \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{a^{n+1}}{n+1} \\
&=& \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_0^a (-x)^n \ \mathrm dx \\
&=& \displaystyle \int_0^a \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-x)^n \ \mathrm dx \\
&=& \displaystyle \int_0^a \frac{1}{1-(-x)} \ \mathrm dx \\
&=& \displaystyle \int_0^a \frac{1}{1+x} \ \mathrm dx \\
&=& \displaystyle \log(1+a)
\end{array}$$
provided that $a>-1$.

> Which one is more correct?

As long as you have shown that the function in concern is [absolutely integrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolutely_integrable_function) with a finite integral, all three methods are justified.

> I used 1. in an exam, and got a really low score

It is best if you ask your teacher *why* you got a low score, instead of complaining here. I cannot make a guess for you, as this would be unfair for the teacher.